# How to set td or cell's trigger unable? I can fire the trigger but do not turn off the trriger

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How to set td or cell's trigger unable? I can fire the trigger but do not  turn off the trriger.I set the trigger like this:

```
 my.contextMenu({
        trigger: '#Grid  td ',
        //leftButton: false,          
        rightButton: true,
        menu: '#testMenu',
        callback: ctxCallback
    });
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What does "I can fire the trigger but do not turn off the trigger" mean? What is "trigger"?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using contextMenu plugin by medialize, according to the doc, you can try:

```
$("#Grid  td").contextMenu(false);
```

to disable trigger.

[Disable a contextMenu trigger](http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/docs.html#disable-trigger)